# Plesk11 Centos6 enabling SMTP port 587

Tags: smtp, centos, plesk

I am using Plesk11 and would like to run my won SMTP service.
My server is configured to work with port 25, yet my ISP doesnt support this, only 587. Could anyone tell me how to configure my host so that SMTP runs on port 587?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Plesk has port 25 open by default , in order to change it without plesk over-writing it again later, and since plesk is running the service using inetd.d structures, you should change the service name.

Add a new service called smtp_plesk under /etc/services with port 587
and after that alter the /etc/xinetd.d/smpt_psa file.

See the following link with a well elaborated guide: http://www.supportfacility.com/blog/plesk/plesk-configure-qmail-to-use-alternate-port-26/